# Show that if $f(x)= \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ and $a_0+\frac{a_1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n}{n+1}=0$, then there is an $x \in (0,1)$ with $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Show that if $f(x)= \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ and $a_0+\dfrac{a_1}{2}+\ldots+\dfrac{a_n}{n+1}=0$, then there is an $x \in (0,1)$ with $f(x)=0.$

Comment: Very similar to A3 on this math competition http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2013.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**.  The main thing you should think of when you read the question is, where on earth did that crazy expression
$$a_0+\frac{a_1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{n+1}$$
come from?  Well, if you integrate
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$
I think you will find out, and hopefully you can then complete the proof.

Comment: I added "crazy" after your comment ;-) ... but seriously, it can be a pretty effective heuristic to closely examine in a problem anything which is surprising or has no obvious motivation, and to try to understand why it's there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the zero point theorem!

if $a_0>0$ and  $\dfrac{a_1}{2}+\ldots+\dfrac{a_n}{n+1}<0$

then the condition you write will turn out to be a critical condition:

$a_0+\dfrac{a_1}{2}+\ldots+\dfrac{a_n}{n+1}=0$

since $f(0)=a_0>0$ and $f(1)=$$-na_0-(n-1)\dfrac{a_1}{2}-\ldots-\dfrac{a_n}{n+1}<0$$\Longrightarrow$$\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{a_{1}}{2}+\frac{n-2}{n}\frac{a_{2}}{3}+......+\frac{1}{n}\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}\le$$\dfrac{a_1}{2}+\ldots+\dfrac{a_n}{n+1}={-a_0}$

a contradiction holds, which imply that $f(0)\cdot{f(1)}\le0$ $,$ then you can use the zero point theorem !

is it helpful ?